# how i can remove the parameter of file in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, parameters

i have problem with my htaccess file 
the problem is : i  have link like www.example.com/PlayList.php?v=1 and i need to convert it to this way www.example.com/PlayList/1

i tried with this code but it's not working with me i dont know way >
there is no error

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/PlayList/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} v
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /PlayList\.php\?v=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /PlayList/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

RewriteRule ^PlayList/(\d+)/?$ PlayList.php?v=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: css is due to your use of relative links. To fix you can add this in the `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />`

Comment: thank you are right it''s work if i enter to the link like example.com/PlayList/1
but it redirect to http://www.example.com/var/www/example/PlayList/1
when i use http://www.example.com/PlayList.php?v=1

Comment: check updated rule, you had missing `RewriteBase` that's why it was using that path.

Comment: thank you sooo sooo soo much yes it's work i forget to use the base one 
:)

Comment: just small question : i get new problem after htaccess updating 
i have ajax code in the same page and it send the info to another page and take response after that  but now i'm getting faild data because the page is not sending any thing , this problem happen just if i use the htaccess that i added to the website ; do you have any idea about that for htaccess ?

Comment: Yes i'm using post method

Comment: @anubhava you're still owning .htaccess :-D

Comment: thank you so much again every thing is work 
@Martin he is really the owner of it :)